# How to update JLabel from a different class?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to update a `JLabel` from a different class, but it doesn't work.
Here are the two classes.

First one is the main class which loads GUI by calling a method `showGUI`. `JLabel` is defined inside this method.
This method also calls the second class `grabScreen` which later needs to update the `JLabel` in the first class.

### magnify

```
public class magnify extends JFrame{
    public final void showGUI(){
      JLabel IL = new JLabel(new ImageIcon());
      panel.add( IL );
      IL.setLocation( 0, 0 );

          int[] a= { 11, 20 };
      grabScreen g= new grabScreen( a );

    } 
//showGUI ends here

   public magnify(){  showGUI(); }

   public static void main( String[] args ){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable(){ public void run(){ magnify rm= new magnify(); rm.setVisible(true); } });
   } 
//main ends here

}
 //magnify class ends here
```

### grabScreen

```
//Second class grabScreen

public class grabScreen  implements Runnable{
   public grabScreen( int[] a ){
    try{
      IL.setIcon( new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File( "sm.jpeg"  ) ) ) );
      // IL is the JLabel in the first class "magnify" inside a method "showGUI"
    }catch(Exception e ){  }

   }
} 
// grabScreen ends here
```

Comment: `grabScreen` will need a reference to `IL` from `magnify`, you will need to pass either via the constructor or a method...

Comment: to update swing UI from runnable use SwingUtilities, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365404/updating-gui-from-a-runnable

Comment: Not related, but why this wastage of space in `magnify` class, why not write everythingy in a single line, why only __main() and constructor__ using this miraculous approach :-) Why not the whole program!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IL` appears to be a local variable defined within the `showGUI` method.  You could declare it as a (public or private) field within the `magnify` class instead.  From within `grabScreen` you will need to be able to access the instance of `magnify` that you've created (either by passing it as a parameter, or assigning it to a field within `grabScreen`).

For example:

```
public class magnify extends JFrame{
    public JLabel IL;  // <-- THE RELEVANT CHANGE

    public final void showGUI(){
      IL = new JLabel(new ImageIcon());
      panel.add( IL );
      IL.setLocation( 0, 0 );

          int[] a= { 11, 20 };
      grabScreen g= new grabScreen( a, this );

    } 
//showGUI ends here

   public magnify(){  showGUI(); }

   public static void main( String[] args ){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable(){ public void run(){ magnify rm= new magnify(); rm.setVisible(true); } });
   } 
//main ends here

}
 //magnify class ends here


//Second class grabScreen

public class grabScreen  implements Runnable{
   public grabScreen( int[] a, magnify myMagnify ){ // <-- CHANGE THIS
    try{
      myMagnify.IL.setIcon( new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File( "sm.jpeg"  ) ) ) );
      // IL is the JLabel in the first class "magnify" inside a method "showGUI"
    }catch(Exception e ){  }

   }
} 
// grabScreen ends here
```

As a style suggestion, Java's normal conventions dictate that classes should be named in `CamelCase` (starting with an upper-case letter), and variables should start with lower-case letters; consequently `magnify` should be named `Magnify`, `grabScreen` should be named `GrabScreen`, and `IL` should probably be named `il` (or something more descriptive).

Comment: 1) `}catch(Exception e ){  }` Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..` 2) `ImageIO.read( new File( "sm.jpeg"  ) )` By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Comment: I did those changes, and the class now compiles. However, it won't run as expected. I get a NullPointException error at line 52, and I'm not sure whats wrong. If I copy this same code from line 52 onwards into "magnify" class directly, it works, but not here.

Comment: @Override  
public void run() {  

b= sr.captureScreenShot(".\\");
try{
Thread.sleep(100);
myM.IL.setIcon( new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File( "sh.jpeg"  ) ) ) );
BufferedImage bigImg = ImageIO.read(new File(".\\sh.jpeg"));
BufferedImage sImg= bigImg.getSubimage( a[0], a[1], 60, 20 );
System.out.println(  sImg.getType() );
BufferedImage mImg= resizeImage( sImg, sImg.getType(), 600, 200  );
ImageIO.write( mImg, "jpg", new File( ".\\", "sm.jpeg")); 
//myM.IL.setIcon( new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File( "sh.jpeg"  ) ) ) );
}catch(Exception e ){ 
e.printStackTrace() ; 
}
}//run

Comment: Thanks guys! You are all amazing! It's working now. I missed to set the values of int[] a which is why I was getting a nullPointerException error when I tried to use it in the resize method.